# Bash: how would I combined these two find commands into one?

Tags: bash, find, path-finding

I have

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra files < <(find / -name "*.lproj" ! -iname "En*" ! -name "Base*" -o -name "*@3x.png" -o -name "*@3x.jpg" -o -name "*@3x.3ds" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/*/iTunesArtwork" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/*/*/*-568h@2x.png" -o -name "*~iphone*" ! -path "*/Kik.app/*" ! -path "*/fiverr.app/*" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/*/*/Library/Caches" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Documents/Flex/*.dat" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/*/*/tmp/*" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Documents/CyDown/*" -o -path "/private/var/db/stash/_.*/Applications/*/*-568h@2x.png" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/*/*/Library/googleanalytics*" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/*/*/Library/*FlurryFiles" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Library/BatteryLife/Archives/*" -o -path "/private/var/tmp/*" -o -path "/private/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Library/Logs/*" -o -path "/private/var/logs/*" -o -path "/private/var/root/.bash_history" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Library/googleanalytics*"  -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/*" -o -path "/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/*"  ! -name "libactivator.plist" -o -iname "*.log" -o -iname "*.old" -o -iname "*.tmp")
du -hc "${files[@]}" 2>/dev/null | tail -1
 rm -r "${files[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And

```
find / -path "/path/to/location" -name '*@2x.png' | sed 's/@2x//' | xargs rm
```

The first one finds files with names and paths specified, counts the total size, then removes them. The second one finds all files ending in "@2x.png" then tries to remove "@2x.png" from the end and then delete the file.

So how might I combine these two commands into one find?

NOTE: there are direct paths and names (in the first command) that end in "@2x.png" that I do not want remove the "@2x.png" from. So I can't just combine them together. e.g (if they were just combined together) having `file@2x.png` in the first command (meaning I would want to remove that exact name) would mean sed would remove the "@2x", which is not what I want to do.

Because I'm bad at explaining things: everything in the first command should have the exact name/path specified, and should **not** be modified by sed. Everything in the second command should be modified by sed, but I want to run only one find command for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive I understand what you're trying to do, but if you still want the array to contain the same things in the first command, but the files from the second

`find / \( -name "*.lproj" ... -iname "*.tmp" \) -print -o -path "/path/to/location" -name '*@2x.png' -exec bash -c 'echo rm "${1/\@2x/}"' bash {} \;`

*Note: Remove `echo` above to do actual `rm`. Also, note if files match the conditions for addition to the array **and** deletion, they will be added to the array but not deleted, per `-o` being short-circuit, if you want the opposite, replace the order.*